# SharePoint calendar display BCS data

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I'm trying to aggregate multiple datasources and display the data in a single SharePoint Calendar.

The datasources are all fed from BCS, coming from a variety of systems.  I have the BCS models / external lists working and the data looks correct.  I know the out of the box web part can't display BCS data in a calendar format...has anyone found a solution?

I'm guessing I'll need to extend the standard SharePoint Calendar web part, has anyone had experience with doing this? Or can anyone provide any tips?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I think OTB sharepoint does not suppport calendar view for bcs lists.

Comment: This is implied in the OP's "I know the out of the box web part can't display BCS data in a calendar format" claim.